# Pause UI in WinRT 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I can't for the life of me get the following functionality to work:

1. User taps item
2. Item's image becomes visible via changing visibility property of image
3. After a short period of time image becomes invisible again (with no user input) via changing the
   visibility property

Or, more simply:

1. Make visible UI change
2. Pause so user can see UI change
3. Reverse step 1's UI change

Step 2 happens before steps 1 and 3 regardless of where the code is because the UI is not updating until the logic finishes (I assume).

I am setting  the visibility of the image via data binding with INotifyPropertyChanged. All works as expected except when I'm trying to introduce the pause.

I'm trying to pause with this simple method:

```
private void Pause()
    {
        new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(1000);
    }
```

It does pause, but the UI changes wait until after that pause even though a change to the bound data happen befores the pause is called, and the other change after.

I have tried using the dispatcher, but it doesn't change anything, and I don't understand it enough:

```
await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
            {
                clickedCard.IsFaceDown = false; // makes the image visible via data binding

            }

            );
Pause();
```

I think I need to do something with threading, but I am going in circles.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should never do something like this inside the UI thread of your app:

```
new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(1000);
```

There are various reasons for not doing it, but in your particular case the problem is that XAML only re-draws once your event-handler completes. So basically this happens:

1. The item is `invisible`
2. Your event handler is called
3. You set it to `visible` (*but the UI doesn't refresh yet*)
4. You freeze the thread for a second
5. You set it to `invisible` again
6. The event-handler completes
7. **Now** the UI updates based on the current value (which is `invisible`)

I suggest you look at building a `Storyboard` to do this - Blend can help. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295300(v=expression.40).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I expected that was what was happening. I can create a storyboard to fade out an image over time, but I have no idea how to make it work on items within a gridview. How do I get the 'cell' of the gridview that has been clicked (as opposed to the bound data that is in e.ClickedItem)?

A storyboard seems comically complicated for such a simple (and presumably common/fundamental) need as 'doing x after an amount of time'.

Comment: Another option is to simply delay in a non-blocking fashion: use `await Task.Delay(1000)` instead of sleep.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, that works. I had tried Task.Delay initially, but I must have got something wrong, which led me to look for the answer in the wrong places!
I just made everything async and added the Task.Delay before switching the image visibility.